# How to customize login error messages in Fortify Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-authentication, laravel-fortify

When users enter wrong username or password they get the following message:

```
These credentials do not match our records.
```

How can I change this message to something like:

```
You have entered an invalid username/password or both. Please try again.
```

I know that I can change the message by editing the following file:

```
App/resources/lang/en/auth.php
```

My question is there a better way like a function for example where I can customize how data is validated?

Actually I'm looking for something like **App/Actions/Fortify/CreateNewUser.php** file that's generated after executing the following command:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Laravel\Fortify\FortifyServiceProvider"
```

Inside this file there's a function named **create($input)** that I can easily manipulate to validate data entered by the users before storing it in the database.

Comment: *"[...] where I can customize the whole login process"* - That's an incredibly broad statement. If you need to customize the whole process, maybe consider not using Laravel Fortify and simply creating your own.

Comment: On fortift , you can chang this from vendor directory, this is not a good idea **vendor > laravel > fortify > src > Rule > Password.php**, instead of these you  need to create a custom Login Controller with your own validation rule

Comment: If you run `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Laravel\Fortify\FortifyServiceProvider"` it should publish a set of files that you can then modify. This might not publish absolutely everything though. For instance the message is still best modified in the localisation files

Comment: Just modify `failed` array key value in the `resources/lang/en/auth.php` file in your application and you will be good to go, and easy to change as well

Comment: I've edited my question. I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Finally I've found the solution by going to this file: vendor/laravel/fortify/src/Actions/AttemptToAuthenticate.php on line 95 change trans('auth.failed') to whatever message you want.

Comment: I add this in \app\Providers\FortifyServiceProvider.php
````
        Fortify::authenticateUsing(function (Request $request) {
            $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();

            if (
                $user &&
                Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)
            ) {
                return $user;
            } else {
                $request->session()->flash('status', 'Wrong credentials, please try again!');
                return false;
            }
        });
````